# How to calculate count of chars in TextView Android?

Tags: java, android

I have the following task:

There is string, and it may have any length: from **1 to 50 symbols**. And there is `TextView` for storing this string.

I need to do the following thing:

if `TextView` can store this string without transferring to next line than `TextView` should store string, but if string is very large than `TextView`,the string should be appended with some chars "..." and shown in `textview`.

For example,if the string is "abdcdereweewew" and `TextView` can contain only 10 symbols on one line, then `TextView` should show "abdcder...". How can I calculate it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually do this by setting the XML-attribute ellipsize on the actual TextView!

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

You should probably also set:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

There are more options with ellipsize, have a look =)